# How to handle load more button in selenium python

Tags: python, html, selenium, web, automation

I am new to python and i am trying to automate click of load more button present in comment section of instagram using selenium and python. I am able to click only once. After first click the button disappears, I have waited for 10 minutes but it did not appear again. And also the status of the request changed to 302 when click in performed using automation. The status code remain 200 when clicked manually. Please help me guys how to perform click until all comment have been loaded. Any help will be appreciated. here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument('start-maximized')

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='./drivers/geckodriver')
browser.maximize_window()

url = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/CKCVIu2gDgn'
browser.get(url)
browser.implicitly_wait(10) #wait for 10 sec
load_more = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div[1]/article/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li/div/button/span').click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use instaloader library, it handles such stuff very easily.
[here](https://instaloader.github.io/) is the full documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, you might want to use Selenium's `excute_script` feature, which basically lets you execute Javascript on the webpage.

The following Javascript code will find the button in the comments and click it.

```js
document.querySelector("button.dCJp8.afkep").click()
```

For such a feat, you would not want to use Selenium to click it because Selenium tries to mimic human behaviour as much as possible. In this case, Selenium would try to find the button, and if it is not visible on the page (ie. you need to scroll to find it), it would raise an Exception.

The following is a line of Python code you can use in your program to click the load more button.

```py
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('button.dCJp8.afkep').click()")
```

By the way, I am  assuming that this round circular plus sign button is the click target.

[image: Instagram load more button]

Comment: thank you for answering , i will try this ...yes this is the button. i am able to click only once, after that it keeps loading and does not appear

Comment: i have tried this, it did not work, means button is clicked once but again disappear. I want to keep clicking the button until all comments are loaded, but after first click it does not appear again, its keep loading itself

Comment: Really? It worked for me. Whenever I click on the load more button, a new one appears after some scrolling.

Comment: not for me, maybe there are some browser issues